# Match Create for multiples in NEO4J

Tags: neo4j

I'm relatively new to Neo4J and was testing manual addition of the Match / Create statements and while I can create them one at a time, the exact same syntax would not create multiples:

[Neo4J Guide Syntax vs Mydata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWHtT.png)

Here is the error I get when I try to add 2 records: Invalid input 'm': expected whitespace, comment or end of input (line 2, column 1)

```
match (from{guid1:'22f3b57daf95435b9ab0d2447f5a79ae'}), 
      (to{guid1:'d960825e3bb843a098c4159873b5ae11'}) 
create from-[:IsValueHas]->to
```

Comment: Here is the error I get when I try to add 2 records: Invalid input 'm': expected whitespace, comment or end of input (line 2, column 1)
"match (from{guid1:'22f3b57daf95435b9ab0d2447f5a79ae'}), (to{guid1:'d960825e3bb843a098c4159873b5ae11'}) create from-[:IsValueHas]->to"

Comment: Can you post your full query and the error?

Comment: @John What do you mean by "add 2 records"? That query attempts to match 2 nodes and, if they are found, create a relationship between them.  Also, the query is legal, and should not have any errors. Are you showing the entire query?

Comment: how did you execute that query?

Comment: your syntax is ok(ish) you should use labels for your nodes.

Comment: I wonder if you're missing a semi-colon.  Are you executing each query individually, or all as one batch?  If it's all in one then it might say `Invalid input 'm': expected` because it ran across a `match` after a `create`

Comment: Individual queries (with a semi-colon on the end) ran successfully.

Comment: Individual queries (with a semi-colon on the end) ran (cut and paste from Excel to the Neo4J browser) successfully. When I tried to run (cut and paste from Excel to the Neo4J browser) two queries (with semi-colons) I get the "Invalid input 'm': expected whitespace, comment or end..." error.  So, in response to Martin - I think I did post the full query and the error; to Michael: via the Neo4J browser; to Michael re: synax: I have several nodes with identical labels so I use GUIDs; and to Brian - apologies for posting the alternate (with no semi-colon) but I did use them in the original queries